# Importing typescript files as modules for python

Tags: python, typescript, playwright

Is there a way to import *.ts* (typescript) files as a module/modules to then be imported into and used by python scripts for playwright?

Comment: Not really, both languages run on very different kinds of runtimes

Comment: Are you trying to run typescript code in the browser through playwright?

Comment: yes that was the plan